# How do I handle the null string from received from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

       function addfav(favor){
         // let a=String(favor.value)
         // console.log(a)
         // console.log(favor)

         let b=document.getElementById(favor).parentElement.parentElement.id
         console.log(b)
         let str=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"))
         //What to do if str is null?
         str.push(b);
         localStorage.setItem("Favorites", JSON.stringify(str))
         document.getElementById(b).style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#5F0A87,#A4508B);";
       }
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function getfav(){
         let i=0;
         var str=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"))
         console.log(str)

         for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
           document.getElementById(str[i]).style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#5F0A87,#A4508B);";
           console.log(document.getElementById(str[i]))
         }

       }


     </script>
```

initially, when my favorite list is empty, it shows up as null and i cant append anything/push anything

given above is the addfav and getfav functions, where addfav is triggered by a click and getfav is triggered on page load

is there any way to prevent null from ocurring/handling the null str?

Comment: And the problem is? Execute a function on page load, read the localStorage (`.getItem()`) and change the elements.

Comment: can you share a snippet to do this please?

Comment: Google (or your preferred search provider) can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `str` before using it...

Example:

```
let str = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorites"));
if (!Array.isArray(str)) {
  str = [];
}
// Use str as an array...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! im a beginner so i dont know of such operations!

Comment: when I run the page locally it works, however , when I upload it to github pages,
it doesnt work, it generates this error
VM103:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0

Comment: Sounds like the JSON your storing in localStorage is invalid. Have you checked the value that you are getting?

Comment: So i just had to use your given snippet in the getfav() function as well! cheers!